# pass additional data to laravel resource

Tags: php, json, laravel, api, resources

i need to pass My custom data to the same level of array of resource but it goes out of array

```
return CategoryProductsResource::collection(Category::whereNull('parent_id')->get())
  ->additional([
                'data' => [
                    'id' => 9999,
                    'name' => 'How Offers',
                    'image' => 'http://businessdotkom.com/storage/categories/January2020/1o6nDi1kjVuwje5FiFXv.png',
                    'products' => ProductIndexResource::collection(Product::whereNotNull('sale_price')->get()),
                ]
            ]);
```

[json output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jNAG.png)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because additional is for top-level data, use `concat` instaed.

```php
return CategoryProductsResource::collection(Category::whereNull('parent_id')->get())
  ->concat([
                'data' => [
                    'id' => 9999,
                    'name' => 'How Offers',
                    'image' => 'http://businessdotkom.com/storage/categories/January2020/1o6nDi1kjVuwje5FiFXv.png',
                    'products' => ProductIndexResource::collection(Product::whereNotNull('sale_price')->get()),
                ]
            ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use PHP `array_merge()` function

```
$categories = Category::whereNull('parent_id')->get()->toArray();

$merged = array_merge($categories, [
           [
             'id' => 9999,
             'name' => 'How Offers',
             'image' => 'http://businessdotkom.com/storage/categories/January2020/1o6nDi1kjVuwje5FiFXv.png',
             'products' => ProductIndexResource::collection(Product::whereNotNull('sale_price')->get()),
           ]
]);

return CategoryProductsResource::collection(collect($merged));
```

Comment: i get error Call to a member function getKey() on integer